# Stationarity in the Almon lag model

Tags: stationarity, autoregressive, polynomial

I have a quick question regarding the Almon approach (Shirley Almon) as presented in    chapter 17 of Gujarati's Basic Econometrics.

In an example given in the textbook, they use non-stationary data and create the polynomia from this, before regressing with OLS. Sadly, they do not comment on the choice of data so I am not sure what to take from it.
Can I use non-stationary data when using the Almon approach?

From all I know one has to make sure that the data is stationary (de-trending, first-difference etc.) when working with autoregressive timeseries models - is that not the case here?

Comment: Perhaps Dave Giles' blog posts on ARDL modelling, [1](http://davegiles.blogspot.no/2013/03/ardl-models-part-i.html) and [2](http://davegiles.blogspot.no/2013/06/ardl-models-part-ii-bounds-tests.html), will help.